# Although Vs Despite

Tags: word-choice

I am always confused about using two words in some situation like this one:

> He managed to win the race (although / despite) hurting his foot before the race.

Could anybody distinguish these two words for me?

Comment: Only one works in the sentence. What research have you done - what do thy mean? How should they be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both but not in the same way although they have the same meaning.
You can use both but not in the same way despite them having the same meaning.

In your case it'd be either

> He managed to win the race despite hurting his foot before the race.

or

> He managed to win the race although he hurt his foot before the race.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/spite-despite-although